# Low performance maybe related with images

Tags: android, performance, imageview

I don't know exactly what happened, I developed a simple memory game that mostly uses ImageViews, at some point all ok in performance terms, but after exported and signed, the game looks so laggy in my xperia sola, it takes too long to press buttons when you just open the game, after 3-4 buttons pressed all go back to normal performance, those issues aren't so noticeable on better devices (xperia sp or lg optimus g as testing examples).
But, the fact is that I have not changed nothing on code either before or after last testings (when game was ok), I just made changes on Images, used a picture editor to remove imperfections on all images and get something more polished, of course game size increased (from 826kb to 1.85mb after edit) and nothing else.

I'd really like to show you code but is too long.
Maybe can you help me to identify the issue?

Comment: Nowhere near enough info to figure it out.  Try running a profiler and see where you're taking all your time.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry, this is an issue where I can't get some error report or warning.
I thought that maybe this could be a common issue